# How to Rebind Listview which is already bind with a datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `Listview` which have a `DataTable` as a `DataSource`. Now i want to rebind it with a Generic list. After that both `Listview` data, `DataTable` and Generic list data will be persisted. Is it possible?

With `DataTable` Binding `Listview` has 3 record.
Now I have a Add Button Outside of the `Listview` and I add a new record in Generic List on Add Button Click, then I temporarily want to display this new record along with the `Listview1. Finally I added this new record on the click of FinalSubmit.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly you want to combine two different data types and essentially merge them into one so you can bind the ListView with it?

If so, you will have to combine both into a SINGLE type. You can you the following code which will convert your generic list into a DataTable (extension method).

```
    /// <summary>
/// Provides extensions to System.Linq object. 
/// </summary>
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the underlying core type for a given type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="typ">Type to evaluate.</param>
    /// <returns>Type.</returns>
    private static Type GetCoreType(Type typ)
    {
        if (typ != null && IsNullable(typ))
        {
            if (!typ.IsValueType)
            {
                return typ;
            }
            else
            {
                return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typ);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return typ;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the type provided is nullable.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="typ">Type to evaluate.</param>
    /// <returns>True if is nullable else false.</returns>
    private static bool IsNullable(Type typ)
    {
        return !typ.IsValueType || (typ.IsGenericType && typ.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a generic list of type T into a data table.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type the list consists of.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="items">Generic list being extended.</param>
    /// <returns>DataTable representing the strongly typed list.</returns>
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this Collection<T> items)
    {
        if (!object.Equals(items, null))
        {
            using (DataTable data = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name))
            {
                data.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
                PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

                foreach (PropertyInfo prop in properties)
                {
                    data.Columns.Add(prop.Name, GetCoreType(prop.PropertyType));
                }
                foreach (T item in items)
                {
                    object[] values = new object[properties.Length];

                    for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
                    {
                        values[i] = properties[i].GetValue(item, null);
                    }
                    data.Rows.Add(values);
                }
                return data;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

You can then merge the two data tables together using the .Merge() method.